# Specifying Column Expiration with TTL in cassandra

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, cql

when i insert value with TTL column expiration it gives me some unexpected output

```
public static void setTTL()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://192.168.1.32/temp");
            String qry = "INSERT INTO userscql3(user_name,password)VALUES('yogesh','temp@123') USING TTL 5";
            Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            smt.executeUpdate(qry);
            System.out.println(" TTL has been set");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After tracing it what i got

```
Caused by: UnavailableException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:33485)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1402)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1388)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:392)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.execute(CassandraConnection.java:416)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:161)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: no Cassandra server is available  ..... ....  this the output i got

Comment: I mean the backtrace. something like `e.printStackTrace()` should be works.

Answer (score 1):

Without backtrace it's difficult to response. But you seem to use Cassandra in an another server than the local host. Did you have configured the listen address of Cassandra? By default it listens only on localhost.

*EDIT*

In `cassandra.yaml` You have to change the `listen_address` and `rpc_address`. Just for the test case you can use: `0.0.0.0`

If you check for the `UnavailableException` in the [Cassandra API](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API) You can read:

> **UnavailableException**
>       Not all the replicas required could be created and/or read.

May be you are using a consistency `ALL` and one of your nodes is down or something like that.

Comment: please see aboe what i got after backtrack

Comment: @thepaul .. sry now i have added it